# Loop the removal of pandas dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I want to loop the deletion of rows until I reach the row with the time value of `04:30:00`, and then stop the deletion process. How do I do that?

Here is an example of my data:

```
ticker  date    time    vol     vwap    open    high    low close
0   AACG    2022-01-06  04:07:00    242 2.0400  2.04    2.04    2.04    2.04
1   AACG    2022-01-06  04:08:00    427 2.0858  2.06    2.10    2.06    2.10
2   AACG    2022-01-06  04:09:00    906 2.1098  2.10    2.11    2.10    2.11
3   AACG    2022-01-06  04:16:00    186 2.1108  2.12    2.12    2.10    2.10
4   AACG    2022-01-06  04:30:00    237 2.0584  2.06    2.06    2.06    2.06
5   AACG    2022-01-06  04:31:00    700 2.1098  2.10    2.11    2.10    2.11
```

I tried this but it doesn't show that anything has changed:

```
row = 0
while df['time'].values[row] == datetime.time(4, 30) == False:
    print(df['time'].values[row])
    df.drop(row, axis=0, inplace=True)
    row = row + 1
```

Here is the `df.info()`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 12 columns):
ticker    10 non-null object
date      10 non-null object
time      10 non-null object
vol       10 non-null int64
vwap      10 non-null float64
open      10 non-null float64
high      10 non-null float64
low       10 non-null float64
close     10 non-null float64
lbh       10 non-null int64
lah       10 non-null int64
trades    10 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(5), int64(4), object(3)
memory usage: 1.1+ KB
```

---

**UPDATE:** Thanks again for your help everyone.

`df[df['time'] >= datetime.time(4, 30)]` helped me remove unnecessary rows.

Comment: Does df['time'] is sorted?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? The data is presented exactly as is pasted in the table above.

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `df.info()` please?

Comment: Sorry, my  question is : Does df['vol'] is sorted? If is bot sorted then is may be tricky.

Comment: Not `df.info` but `df.info()` <- missing parenthesis.

Comment: Hi hpchavaz, None of these columns are sorted, This is how the data looks after I pull it from an API

Comment: Ive updated the df.info() into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop here if you convert your `time` column to a `TimedeltaIndex`:

```
out = df[~pd.to_timedelta(df['time']).lt('04:30:00')]
print(out)

# Output
  ticker        date      time         vol  vwap  open  high  low close
4   AACG  2022-01-06  04:30:00  237 2.0584  2.06  2.06  2.06       2.06
5   AACG  2022-01-06  04:31:00  700 2.1098  2.10  2.11  2.10       2.11
```

Does it work?

```
from datetime import time

out = df[df['time'] >= time(4, 30)]
print(out)

# Output:
  ticker        date      time         vol  vwap  open  high  low close
4   AACG  2022-01-06  04:30:00  237 2.0584  2.06  2.06  2.06       2.06
5   AACG  2022-01-06  04:31:00  700 2.1098  2.10  2.11  2.10       2.11

# Info
print(df['time'].iloc[0])
# datetime.time(4, 7)
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm afraid that doesn't work. I get "ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'datetime.time'>"

Comment: Im not sure why the time values make it so tricky

Comment: @lmac. What is the output of `type(df['time'].iloc[0])`?

Comment: Hi @Corralien, the output is datetime.time

Comment: I updated my answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for responding, I took your updated answer. it works when I add "datetime." right before where you put "time(4,30)". Thanks so much for helping me with this. The different time data types can be confusing at times.

Answer (score 2):

Don't loop but slice. You can use a mask for that (here generated with a boolean array and `cummax`):

```
df[df['time'].eq('04:30:00').cummax()]
```

output:

```
  ticker        date      time  vol    vwap  open  high   low  close
4   AACG  2022-01-06  04:30:00  237  2.0584  2.06  2.06  2.06   2.06
5   AACG  2022-01-06  04:31:00  700  2.1098  2.10  2.11  2.10   2.11
```

If you also want to exclude the matching row:

```
df[df['time'].eq('04:30:00').shift(fill_value=False).cummax()]
```

Comment: This isnt working either. It removes everything except the headers

Comment: @Imac use whatever type you need in `eq`. I showed the example for string here, if datetime use `datetime.time(4,30)` in place of `'04:30:00'`

Comment: @Imac please note that the other two solutions only work if the times are sorted. This one works as you described in the question, dropping all rows until the first match is found, irrespective of the order of time.

Comment: Thank you @mozway. The df would ideally have the time column sorted always.

Answer (score 2):

This solution

1. combines the `"date"` and `"time"` columns into a new `datetime.datetime` column,
2. searches for the first occurrence of the given time, and
3. deletes rows up to but excluding the first occurrence of the given time.

---

- If the given time is not found, nothing gets removed because `row_ix_of_first_occurrence` will equal to `0`.
- The solution works for both integer index and string index.

```py
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd


def parse_date_time(date: str, time_24: str) -> datetime:
    return datetime.strptime(" ".join((date, time_24)), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO("""ticker  date    time    vol     vwap    open    high    low close
AACG    2022-01-06  04:07:00    242 2.0400  2.04    2.04    2.04    2.04
AACG    2022-01-06  04:08:00    427 2.0858  2.06    2.10    2.06    2.10
AACG    2022-01-06  04:09:00    906 2.1098  2.10    2.11    2.10    2.11
AACG    2022-01-06  04:16:00    186 2.1108  2.12    2.12    2.10    2.10
AACG    2022-01-06  04:30:00    237 2.0584  2.06    2.06    2.06    2.06
AACG    2022-01-06  04:31:00    700 2.1098  2.10    2.11    2.10    2.11"""),
    delim_whitespace=True,
    parse_dates={"datetime": ["date", "time"]},
    date_parser=parse_date_time,
    index_col=False,
    header=0,
    engine="python",
    keep_date_col=False,
)

print(f"DataFrame initially:\n{df.to_string()}\n")

is_given_time = (
    (df["datetime"].dt.hour == 4)
    & (df["datetime"].dt.minute == 30)
    & (df["datetime"].dt.second == 0)
)
row_ix_of_first_occurrence = is_given_time.argmax()
row_ix_delete = df.index[:row_ix_of_first_occurrence]
df = df.drop(index=row_ix_delete)

print(f"DataFrame after filtering:\n{df.to_string()}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean mask to slice your data. If your `df['time']` is datetime.time objects, then you can slice `df` simply as:

```
out = df[df['time'] > datetime.time(4,30)]
```

Output:

```
  ticker        date      time  vol    vwap  open  high  low  close
5   AACG  2022-01-06  04:31:00  700  2.1098   2.1  2.11  2.1   2.11
```